# How to do scanning screen

Tags: c#

i want ask this. I want make programm to monitoring, scanning monitor/screen and when find specifict item/pixel color, so then something to do, action-clicing to this area/place. can i make it in c# or....

For scanning mayby:

```
Bitmap bitmap = new Bitmap(Screen.PrimaryScreen.Bounds.Width,
          Screen.PrimaryScreen.Bounds.Height);
    Graphics graphics = Graphics.FromImage(bitmap as Image);
    graphics.CopyFromScreen(0, 0, 0, 0, bitmap.Size);

    bool found = false;

    bool one = true;
    bool two = false;

    int x = 0;
    int y = 0;

    Bitmap myBitmap = bitmap;
    while (found != true)
    {
        Color pixelColor = myBitmap.GetPixel(x, y);
        if (pixelColor == Color.FromArgb(0, 0, 0))
        {
            Cursor.Position = new Point(x, y);
            found = true;
        }
        if (one == true)
        {
            x = x + 1;
            if (x >= 1920)
            {
                one = false;
                two = true;
                x = 0;
            }
        }
        else if (two == true)
        {
            y = y + 1;
            if (y >= 1080)
            {
                y = 0;
            }
            one = true;
            two = false;
        }
    }
```

PLS for same idea or is it possible ?

Comment: Can you please add some more information? What exactly are you going to be looking for on the screen? Are you looking for text or just a specific object?